# lapply does not seem to be a pure map function (or is this a string problem)?

Tags: r, lapply

I am using R 3.5.2.

As I read the documentation, I was expecting

```
lapply(c(a,b),f) == c(f(a),f(b))
```

But I get ...

```
f = function(x) x

b = c("1","0","0")

lapply(b,f)

[[1]]
[1] "1"

[[2]]
[1] "0"

[[3]]
[1] "0"
```

While I also get

```
c(f("1"),f("0"),f("0"))
[1] "1" "0" "0"e
```

I tried using sapply and got a different problem ...

```
sapply(c("1","0","0"),f)

 1   0   0 
"1" "0" "0"
```

But sapply works on a numeric list ...

```
sapply(c(1,0,0),f)
[1] 1 0 0
```

---

So, how do I get just c(f(a),f(b)), generically ?

Comment: `lapply` returns a list.  Use `sapply` to get the desired vector.  Or do `unlist(lapply(...))`

Comment: It is just a named `vector`,, you can either do `as.vector` or `unname` to remove the names. i.e `unname(sapply(c("1", "0", "0"), f))`

Comment: Thanks both @DanY and akrun. That's spot on. The USE.NAMES=FALSE is the most usuable in my context. But, I appreciate all the info I got from this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `USE.NAMES` argument in `sapply` is `TRUE` by default.  It can be set to FALSE

```
sapply(c("1","0","0"),f, USE.NAMES = FALSE)
#[1] "1" "0" "0"
```

Or other options are wrap with `unname` or `as.vector` or `unlist` as all of these strips off the attribute.  The output of `sapply` in OP's post is a `named` `vector` i.e. it includes the name as attributes.  By wrapping with `unname`, `as.vector`, it removes the attribute

```
unname(sapply(c("1", "0", "0"), f))
#[1] "1" "0" "0"
```